# How do i compare the performance of two multiclass confusion matrix?

Tags: comparison, confusion-matrix

So I have two multiclass confusion matrices from two different classifiers for ten classes.
Both used the same input data.
I want to know how I will compare the two to choose which is the better one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.